# Where do Visual Studio Intellisense comments come from?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, intellisense

Visual Studio projects have an option to create **XML Documentation Files**.
I understand that XML Documentation Files can be useful if you'd like to run a program like Sandcastle or NDoc or whatever to create MSDN-Style API docs. Fine. I don't care about that.

According to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0we08bk.aspx

> When you add the /doc switch to the Visual Basic, C#, or C++ compiler command line, an .xml file is generated that serves as the basis for IntelliSense documentation.

So that makes me think that Intellisense comments **can** appear from these generated XML files.

But I created a little Test app where I call a method in a totally different project and the XML comment appears in my Intellisense — And I haven't even saved the MediaHelper class! So in this case it's obvious there is no .xml file that Intellisense is using.

[image: Comment from Un-Saved Class]

In light of all this, where does Intellisense get it's junk from?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When the source code is within the existing solution (or even better, the same project), Visual Studio doesn't need to find an XML file - it knows where the documentation comments are, so it will use them. (Just like Intellisense knows what members you've declared in the other file, even if you haven't actually rebuilt yet.)

You need to create an XML file if you want to add a reference to a DLL rather than a project reference within the same solution. So for example, I supply NodaTime.xml with the Noda Time package, so that even though you don't have the source code, you can still see the comments in Intellisense.

Comment: Jon, this is amazing. You answered my question within 3 minutes of asking. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: Some coworkers shared a great reason why our team was generating XML Documentation. On a large, global team like ours, it forces everyone to **document their code**. This only works if you have "Treat Warnings As Errors" turned on. So, you will not be able to compile without documenting your code.

Answer (score 5):

Intellisense gets it from its XML comments.

For example, let's say I have a class:

```
///<summary>
/// This is an example class
///</summary>
static class Foo
{
    //members
}
```

In fact, you can go even deeper than that. For example, a method:

```
///<summary>
///Returns the object to string, uppercased.
///</summary>
///<param name="o">The object to be transformed.</param>
///<returns>The string.</returns>
public string someMethod(object o)
{
   return o.ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I know that it comes from XML comments but I guess I worded my question badly. Jon Skeet understood what I was trying to get at and answered my question.

Comment: Thank you though. I guess my real question was "what are XML documentation files good for other than MSDN-style docs"?