# What is Newtonsoft.Json.xml?

Tags: json.net

I'm new to `Newtonsoft.Json`.
I see two files: `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.xml`.

What is the xml file for? Do I need to copy it to the bin folder?

Comment: It's the code documentation. It's not necessary, but you probably want to have it so you can read what methods/classes/properties etc. do.

Comment: That means I should not deploy the file with my application to customers?

Comment: Yes. You don't need it anywhere else than in your IDE.

Comment: See [Where do Visual Studio Intellisense comments come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14530949/10263) and [Is it necessary to deploy the XML file in a class library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32191906/10263)