# visual studio (dont show information about the methods, properties etc....)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am currently with VS 2015. I want to see this:

[image]

Instead of that I see only (for example `Length(int Array.Length{get;})`).

Comment: Does the library you are referencing include an XML documentation file?  That's where the information comes from.

Comment: well... I am not so into programming. I thought Microsoft developers write that documentation file. Do you know how to chek and fix it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530949/where-do-visual-studio-intellisense-comments-come-from i dont understand anything of this.

Comment: Does this happen only with that `FromSwapChain` method? What if you enter, for example, `string.Format(`?.

Answer (score 0):

First try : `ctrl + shift + space`

if it dosn't work, then :

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General
```

and check the options `with overriding 'mixed' check`:

- Auto list members
- Parameter information

Comment: try the ctrl + shift + space .

Comment: Yes, but in this case doesnt show explanation(what is this thing doing)

Comment: try to uncheck the options in the answer and then check them again. sometimes, even closing and reopening the projects can correct it. Either than that, I'm running out of ideas... Good luck :)